# What is the difference between \number and \the?

Tags: macros

I am trying to learn more about macro programming - if that's the right word - in TeX and LaTeX.  I began by defining a quantity I called Sum : `\newcount\Sum`.  I then wrote `\Sum=0`.  Then I did some arithmetical operations on Sum, by using `\multiply . . . by . . .`  and `\advance . . . by . . .`.

Finally I wanted to print out (in the document) the value of Sum. For that I used the line

```
 The Sum equals **\number**\Sum ,
```

and it worked as expected !  But later on, I discovered that I might just as well have written

```
The Sum equals **\the**\Sum ".
```

And now I wonder which of the two is the preferred way to write out a numerical value.  Are they equivalent ?  Or are they intended for different purposes - even if the results overlap in my example ?

Here is an MWE:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%
%% Here is the example tex-file that illustrates use of \number and \the .   
%%                                           
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4in, paperheight=0.8in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newcount\a  \newcount\b  \newcount\Sum

\a=1   \b=5  \Sum=0
\advance\Sum by \a  \multiply\Sum by \b
\advance\Sum by \a  \multiply\Sum by \b

\noindent
The Sum equals \number\Sum  \quad;\quad I used ``number''.
\par \vskip 10pt \noindent
The Sum equals \the\Sum     \quad;\quad I used ``the''.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of describing the problem, It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem, and perhaps added the description as comments.

Comment: A related question is why I was not allowed to define variables, or counters, by giving them names such as x1, x2, . . .  It seemed as if the names I wanted to use were not allowed to contain numbers -- only letters were allowed. Is there a way around this ?

Comment: You should ask about this as a separate question.

Comment: **Regarding the performance**: when followed by `\numexpr`, `\the` is faster. [tex core - The difference between `\the\numexpr` and `\number\numexpr` - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307318/the-difference-between-the-numexpr-and-number-numexpr)

Answer (score 17):

`\number` and `\the` are similar on a count register.  `\the` may be applied to more types, such as

```
\the\dimen0
```

or

```
\the\everypar
```

or

```
 \the\font
```

Using `\number` on those cases is either an error or (in the first case) casts the dimen to a number, taking its value is `sp` units.