# The difference between `\the\numexpr` and `\number\numexpr`

Tags: tex-core, e-tex

I wonder if there is any functional difference between `\the\numexpr` and `\number\numexpr`. Some obscure context where they would yield different results?

(I'm obviously aware that `\the` and `\number` differ, wildly. I'm just curious about the case where they are followed by `\numexpr`.)

Comment: Without actually knowin anything, I always thought that `\number` was `\the` with the only difference that if followed by a dimension it would print the number of `sp`. What are the differences?

Comment: In one sentence: `\the` expands to the value of an (any) internal quantity, while `\number` expands to the decimal representation of a number (integer).

Comment: I don't think there are any differences assuming the csnames refer to the primitives., but would need to cite etex web sources to really justify an answer:-)

Comment: @Manuel compare `\the\font` and `\number\font`

Answer (score 10):

While it seems that there is no difference in semantics (but I'm still waiting for answers here), there seems to be a small but consistent difference in performance.

First, `\the` consists of 4 characters and `\number` of 7, so you can type it almost twice as fast! ;-)

Seriously, `\the\numexpr` seems to be 10 - 15% faster than `\number\numexpr`. As it's not absolutely trivial to measure this, this is how I did it.

I ran `pgf`'s `profiler` library on these three loops:

L1. `\edef\a{\the\numexpr 40+2}`

L2. `\edef\a{\number\numexpr 40+2}`

L3. `\edef\a{}`

... in the hope that subtracting the execution time of L3 from L1 (L2) gives me the time actually spent in `\the\numexpr` (`\number\numexpr`). `(L1-L3) / (L2-L3)` then yields about 85 - 90%.

To get a rough feel for the actual speed: a million repetitions of `\the\numexpr` takes about a second on my computer.

Comment: It's known that `\the` performs better than `\number`.

Comment: @egreg I had no idea. But it makes sense. And there's nothing like personal experience! ;-)

Comment: all of `xint` uses `\the\numexpr` because of that. Other thing: `\number\dimexpr` is useful as it gives integer number in `sp` units. And a `\dimexpr` inside a `\numexpr` is tacitly converted this way.

Comment: Remark: While it seems `\the` is more general, it can only take *internal* objects while `\number 12` results in `12`, so it makes sense that `\the` is faster.